# display buffer in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to display a buffer but it's being displayed with special characters.  Here's my code:

```
size_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{

    static size_t (*write_func)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;
    if (!write_func)
        write_func = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");


    char tmp[count];  

    memcpy(tmp,buf,count);
    printf("  %c \n",tmp[1]);
```

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?  Thank you so much!

Comment: What does `write_func` have to do with this?  How were `buf` and `count` populated?

Comment: If count is `1`, `tmp[1]` is out of bounds as arrays run from `0 to N - 1`

Comment: i use the linux interposition mechanism to redirect the write function and modify the buffer

Answer (score 0):

You allocate a copy of the read-only data on stack. That is dangerous, since stack space may be limited. (In Linux, only the original stack will grow dynamically; thread stacks are of fixed size, and often very small.)

Then you use the stdio.h `printf()` function to output the second byte of the specified data (even though `count` may be 1) to standard output, so you're likely to access outside of the temporary array anyway.

Most `printf()` implementations call `write()` internally to flush the buffer. Depending on the linkage, this may end up being recursive (your function calling `printf` which calls your function which calls `printf` and so on), using up all RAM available to the process, then crashing.

None of the above makes sense.

First, if you need to duplicate the input data, do it dynamically using `malloc()` and `memcpy()`, then `free()` it afterwards. That way you don't suddenly start causing crashes in multithreaded programs (where stack space is limited and fixed for all but the original process in Linux).

Second, you need to use the original `write_func` you obtained using the linker.

Third, you need to retain `errno` to avoid unforeseen problems in client programs. Just use a temporary local `int` to store it. Remember that not only `write()`, but also `malloc()` and `free()` may modify `errno`, and you must hide those changes from the caller.

Fourth, the return type of `write()` is `ssize_t`, not `size_t`. The former is signed, the latter may be unsigned.

Fifth, short writes are always allowed. You cannot ever rely on getting a "full" chunk; applications do internal processing, and especially when working with sockets, flush it at odd sizes (multiples of MTU for TCP/IP and UDP/IP in particular). Your "modifications" to the input/output would have to be stateless. Worse, if your modifications change the buffer length, and the descriptor is nonblocking, and the `write_func()` call returns a short write just in the middle of the modified part that does not map sensibly to any original byte, how are you going to handle it? You cannot retry, really, since the descriptor is nonblocking; the original application might hang -- for example if used in a coprocess manner, simultaneously sending and receiving data from a peer process with strict ordering requirements -- because your additions would reissue a write when one is not allowed at the application logic level.

Simply put, your scheme is not going to work. You might get it to work with some specific simple applications, but it can break others horribly. Whatever you're trying to achieve, there is a better way.

I hope I am not being too blunt, but I seriously suggest you first learn the ins and outs of low-level POSIX I/O, before you create wrappers around them. The [Linux man-pages project](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/dir_all_by_section.html) is a good reference I can recommend, but I think you might need to start with some tutorials first.

Comment: Really thank you very much for all explanations, my test application is a client that sends a character to the server, the server  increments and sends the next character. My goal is to attach to the message sent two other characters and at reception I store these two characters in a file I have considered all your comments, here is the code :

Comment: ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) 
{

static size_t (*write_func)(int, const void *, size_t) = NULL;
if (write_func == NULL) { write_func = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write"); if (!write_func) { printf("ERROR: cannot load 'write': "); puts(dlerror()); exit(-1); } } if (!write_func) write_func = (size_t(*)(int, const void *, size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write"); char * tmp; tmp = malloc (sizeof(char)); memcpy(tmp,buf,count);

char buffer[100]={'1','2'};
int i;
int j=0;
for(i=strlen(tmp);i< strlen(tmp)+strlen(buffer);i++)
{tmp[i]=buffer[j];j++;
}return write_func(fd, tmp,strlen(tmp));}

Comment: I wait all your comments please, I also wonder if in my case I have also use the mechanism with interposition read to store the char in the file?